# Jquery slide toggle hide and show

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easing

I need to hide one div and show another using slide function of jQuery.

In hide function, I am using this code

```
$("id").hide("slide", { direction: 'left' },1000);
```

and in show I am using this code:

```
$("id").show("slide", { direction: 'left' },1000);
```

and making an ajax call to hide and show these divs:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",

            url: '@Url.Action("tabSetting", "Home")',

            async: "true",

            beforeSend: function () {

                hidediv();

            },

            success: function (data) {

                $("#settings").html(data);

            },

            complete: function () {

                showdiv();

            }

        });
```

But with this code I get an error *"TypeError: b.easing[this.easing] is not a function"*

Comment: I think the `showdiv()` can be used in the `success`.

Comment: @jogesh_pi and why would you do that?

Comment: @jogesh_pi but it doesn't solve the problem, nor is it better. Please post only usefull and related comments...

Comment: Have you included jquery ui with easing?

Comment: I got the solution by adding these two j query UI files 
`<script src="~/scripts/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery.effects.slide.js"></script>`